# Prevent useEffect infinite loop when updating NextJs query string

Tags: next.js, use-effect, next-router

I have a tag input that produces an array of tags. Using NextJs's useRouter, I want to add those tags as query string params as they are added. I also need to preserve the current query string params, since other filters, searches, and pagination need to remain.

Here is how I'm currently doing it.

```
const router = useRouter();
const { query } = router;
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  router.push({
    query: {
      ...query,
      tags,
    },
  });
}, [tags, router, query]);

return (
  <>
    <TagInput tags={tags} setTags={setTags} placeholder="Search by tags" />
  </>
);
```

However, this causes an infinite render since the useEffect updates the `query` but also has `query` as a dependency. If I remove `query` as a dependency, it works fine, but I get the missing dependency linting error.

Edit: Here is a codesandbox with a minimal example that reproduces the issue. It works as is, but if you uncomment the `query` dependency, infinite loop.
https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-dynamic-routing-forked-rlxuqh?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Are tags the only thing that you're storing in the query object? The example (inside router.push) makes it look like there might be other values stored in the query object.

Comment: @StaffordRose there are others, as I said in the question I also need to preserve the current query string params, since other filters, searches, and pagination need to remain.

Comment: @lpizzinidev The TagInput component is a little big and I think would distract from the main question since the tag input doesn't seem to have an effect, I just added a codesandbox link that lets you add tags with just a button to demonstrate that. It works as is but as soon as you uncomment the query dependency the infinite loop starts before you can even add any tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this can be done is to directly update the query object and read the tags from the url, rather than storing the tags in state.

```js
const router = useRouter();
const { query } = router;

const setTags = useCallback((tags) => {
  router.push({
    query: {
      ...query,
      tags
    }
  });
}, [router, query]);

return (
  <>
    <TagInput tags={query.tags || []} setTags={setTags} placeholder="Search by tags" />
  </>
);
```